# Angularjs File Upload code Error

Tags: angularjs

I'm getting an error in angularjs file upload.

Here this my code:

[image: html]

I am getting error in console log:

```
angular.js:10765 POST http://localhost/kites/upload/ 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: Welcome! put your code example that what you try for. and visit link **[How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**

Comment: Do NOT post pictures of code. Post the code itself!

Comment: You probably just need to tell it what port number you are sending it as localhost. (ex: 'http://localhost:9002/kites/upload'/ )

Answer (score 1):

**Use this code**

**in simple words**

***in Html -***  add below code only

```
     <form name="upload" class="form" data-ng-submit="addFile()">
  <input type="file" name="file" multiple 
 onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadedFile(this)" />
 <button type="submit">Upload </button>
</form>
```

***in the controller*** -  This function is called when you click **"upload file button"**. it will upload the file. you can console it.

```
$scope.uploadedFile = function(element) {
$scope.$apply(function($scope) {
  $scope.files = element.files;         
});
  // console.log($scope.files)  
  //  uploaded file is in  $scope.files

}
```

***add more in controllers*** - below code add into the function . This function is called when you click on  button which is used  **"hitting the api (POST)"**. it will send file(which uploaded) and form-data to the backend .

```
var url = "https://192.3.3.22/api/vi/userapi/reporttojson"
// use can put you api in 'url' variable
        var files=$scope.files;

         for ( var i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
         {
            var fd = new FormData();
             angular.forEach(files,function(file){
             fd.append('file',file);
             });
             var data ={
              msg : message,
              sub : sub,
              sendMail: sendMail,
              selectUsersAcknowledge:false
             };

             fd.append("data", JSON.stringify(data));
              $http.post(url, fd, {
               withCredentials : false,
               headers : {
                'Content-Type' : undefined
               },
             transformRequest : angular.identity
             }).success(function(data)
             {
                  toastr.success("Notification sent successfully","",{timeOut: 2000});
                  $scope.removereport()
                   $timeout(function() {
                    location.reload();
                }, 1000);

             }).error(function(data)
             {
              toastr.success("Error in Sending Notification","",{timeOut: 2000});
              $scope.removereport()
             });
        }
```

in this case .. i added below code as form data

```
var data ={
          msg : message,
          sub : sub,
          sendMail: sendMail,
          selectUsersAcknowledge:false
         };
```